# Unable to understand this particular program

Tags: java

I'm finding it difficult to understand what is happening in this program code.
Please help. 
Thanks

```
public class ArrayTriangle
{ 
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int[][] triangle = new int[10][];
        for ( int j = 0; j<triangle.length ; j++ )

            triangle[ j ] = new int[ j + 1 ];         /*Please explain me this line*/
    }
}
```

Comment: `triangle[0] = new int[1];`
`triangle[1] = new int[2];` and so on..

Comment: @Dibya You're right, my bad.

Comment: `new int[ j + 1 ]; ` creates a new array of size `j + 1`.

Comment: As the name implies, it creates a data structure in the shape of triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a 2-D array

```
triangle[0] = new int[1];
triangle[1] = new int[2];
triangle[2] = new int[3];
```

You can will will have a 2-D array with 0th element having size of 1, 1st with 2 and so on.

This is the output if you print the array which is clearly a triangle.

```
for (int j = 0; j < triangle.length; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < triangle[j].length ; k++){
            System.out.print(triangle[j][k]);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Use the above snippet to see print your triangle.

```
[[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is creating an array of array, like this

```
triangle[ 0 ] = new int[ 1 ];
triangle[ 1 ] = new int[ 2 ];
triangle[ 2 ] = new int[ 3 ];
...
```